# jQuery - Reg exp only 1-9 and once a time a point

Tags: jquery, regex, numbers, digits

Reg exps. are not my power. Here are my line of code:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[(1-9)(\.)]\d*$");
```

Now I can input: 1-9 and so many points as I want. Problem: I want only give the user the opportunity for exactly write one point.

How can I do that? Here are my whole script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.bet-bit-input').keypress(function (e) {
            var regex = new RegExp("[(1-9)(\.)]\d*$");
            var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
            if (regex.test(str)) {
                return true;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
    });
});
```

Thanks for any helpin'

Answer (score 0):

Replace your regex with `^\d+(\.\d+)?$`

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?$
```

**explanation:**

```
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [1-9]                    any character of: '1' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

your regex `^[(1-9)(\.)]\d*$` means:

```
 ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  [(1-9)(\.)]              any character of: '(', '1' to '9', ')',
                           '(', '\.', ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
```

Comment: ^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d+)?$ is not working for me. I can type numbers from 1-0 BUT no point. Why?

    http://jsfiddle.net/6CJzC/

Comment: @user2814327: What do you mean by `BUT no point`? Could you give examples that must pass and some that must failed?